# Is it possible to restrict content editors to specific content in UmbracoCMS

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

So here is my situation, I have an umbraco website which is divided into sections for each department in an organisation. Each organisation wishes to manage its own content and want their own admin. However they don't want the admins of other departmetns to be able to modify the content outside their own department.

Is there a way to restrict content writers to have access to edit content only in a specific part of the umbraco backend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, when creating the new user you can set the starting node of the Content and Media so he will be able to only modify those pages and their children

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Eyescream's answer above, you can also set permissions for pages as well. If you right click on the node in the tree, and select "permissions" from the list of options, you can set permissions on specific actions for that node for each user as well. E.g. you can make it so that certain users cannot delete or move certain nodes.